# Why does the code print 'test' instead of a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Java “pass-by-reference”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Why does the code below print 'test' instead of throwing a `NullPointerException`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("test");
    append(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}

public static void append(StringBuilder sb) {
    sb = null;
}
```

Comment: If you step through your code in a debugger you will see what each line of code is doing and it will make this much clearer.

Answer (score 5):

You are setting the local variable `sb` in the method `append()` to `null` - that does not affect the calling environment's variable, it remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Because your custom append model isn't returning sb back to the parent method. and therefore `System.out.println(sb.toString());` is simply returning the sb method in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you a assign a value to a method parameter, it maintains the new value *only* within the scope of that method.  In other words it would throw a NPE if you placed the `System.out.println(sb)` inside the `append` method.